# struts tiles 1.3 on tomcat 9 jdk 1.8 [Error] No action config found for the specified url

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, tiles, struts-1

I have an application running struts and struts-tiles 1.3 on a JBoss 5.1 Server with 1.6 JDK without problems.
once I migrated to a Tomcat 9 server with 1.8 JDK I start getting an ERROR :

```
GRAVE: "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet [action] a lancé une exception
org.apache.struts.chain.commands.InvalidPathException: No action config found for the specified url.
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractSelectAction.execute(AbstractSelectAction.java:71)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:895)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtilImpl.doInclude(TilesUtilImpl.java:129)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesUtil.doInclude(TilesUtil.java:152)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doInclude(InsertTag.java:764)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag$InsertHandler.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:896)
    at org.apache.struts.tiles.taglib.InsertTag.doEndTag(InsertTag.java:465)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsert_005f0(layout_jsp.java:2297)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.pages.layout.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:647)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
....
```

Can any one help me please ?

The error occur when I access the application URL : http://localhost:8080/myapp/authentification.do

specifically when server renders `layout.jsp` at `tiles:insert` tag :

```
<tiles:insert attribute="corner" />
```

The page is rendered with a tiles template layout.jsp
snippet from layout.jsp :

```
<body>
        <div id="loading"></div>
        <c:set var="selectedTab" scope="request"><tiles:getAsString name="selectedTab"/></c:set>

        <c:if test="${sessionScope.utilisateur !=null}">
            <div id="bulle"><img src="${imgBulle}" border="0" /></div>
        </c:if>
                    <div id="corner"><tiles:insert attribute="corner" /></div>  

        <div id="container">
            <div id="top">
                <div id="title">                        
                    <h1><%@ include file="/WEB-INF/pages/include/title.jsp"%></h1>      
                    <div id="logo"><img src="${imgLogo}" border="0" /></div>



                </div>
            </div>
```

related configuration from tiles.xml :

```
    <definition name="page_corner" page="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/corner.jsp" />
<definition name="template" path="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/layout.jsp">
        <put name="title" value="" />
        <put name="corner" value="page_corner" />
        <put name="messages" value="Messages" />
        <put name="informations" value="Informations" />
        <put name="content" value="" />
        <put name="tabs" value="" />
        <put name="selectedTab" value="" />
    </definition>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem and the application is running now.
The issue is due to JSP 2.3 engine hence when `tiles:insert` calls an attribute defined with an empty value it trigger the error.

The solution that worked for me is to create an empty jsp file `empty.jsp`, define it in tiles and use it wherever I need.

Solution:

```
<definition name="page_empty" page="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/empty.jsp" />
```

and the above (in the question) template configuration would be :

```
<definition name="template" path="/WEB-INF/pages/layout/layout.jsp">
    <put name="title" value="" />
    <put name="corner" value="page_corner" />
    <put name="messages" value="Messages" />
    <put name="informations" value="Informations" />
    <put name="content" value="page_empty" />
    <put name="tabs" value="page_empty" />
    <put name="selectedTab" value="page_empty" />
</definition>
```

PS: `<put name="corner" value="page_corner" />` defined in `template` was not the source of the problem but an other `<put name="corner" value="" />` defined in `tiles_login` that extends `template`.

```
<definition name="tiles_login" extends="template">
    <put name="title" value="application.authentification.title" />
    <put name="corner" value="" />
    <put name="bandeau" value="" />
    <put name="content" value="" />
</definition>
```